# Javascript mini validation script

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm new to js. trying to create mini validation function which will check fields if they're empty or not.

What i wanna do is, to call func like that `checkIfEmpty("fullname, email,...")`, then inside function, check each field seperated by comma, collect empty fields to one array, and check at the end if this array is empty or not. Tried something like following func, but don't know all alternatives of php functions in js. Please help me to realize my idea..

```
function checkIfEmpty(fields)
{
    var emptyFields=new Array();
    fields=fields.split(',');
    foreach(fields as field)
    {
        if (!field.val()) {
            field.attr('class', 'invalid');
            emptyFields[] = field;
        }
        }
        if(emptyFields.length()==0){return true;}
        else {return false;}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you donk't know all alternative of php function in js?

Comment: if you are using the jQuery library, jquery-validate is quite good.

Comment: I'm php developer, new to js. For ex I don't know `foreach` loops alternative in js

Comment: @DavidNguyen which validation plug-in? I need something with custom error handling

Comment: check out http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/. It has a bunch of standard validation tools and is extensible so you can right your own validation functions. It easily handles your function above though, and will probably be more robust and functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this:

```
$("input:text").each(function(i, field) {
     if (!field.val()) {
         field.addClass('invalid');
     }
});
return ($("input.invald").length > 0); // return true if invalid fields
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set a class on each input that not suppose to be empty, then on form submission check each input that has this class.

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() {
    $('.required').each(function() {
        // if a input field that's required is empty
        // we add the class '.invalid' 
        if(!$(this).val()) {
           $(this).addClass('invalid');
        }
    });

    // prevent the submission if number
    // there is required fields still empty
    return ($('input.invalid').length == 0);
});
```

This is an example form with one required field called `email`:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="email" class="required" />
  <input type="text" name="firstname" />
  <input type="text" name="lastname" />
  <input type="submit" value="SEND" />
</form>
```